# Boundedness of solution for differential equation $ y^{\prime}(t)+y(t)=f(t) $ relative to the boundedness of $f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Consider the differential equation
$$
y^{\prime}(t)+y(t)=f(t)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*)
$$
on $\mathbb{R}$.

a) Show that $(*)$ can have at most one bounded solution.

b) If $f$ is bounded, show that $(*)$ has a bounded solution.

Actually, we have $y_h(t)=e^{-t}$ as a solution for corresponding homogeneous part $y'(t)+y(t)=0$, which is not a bounded function on $\Bbb R$. Further, a particular solution $y_p(t)=(D+I)^{-1}(f)(t),$ where $D=\frac{d}{dt}$, should be obtained to get the general solution $y=y_h+y_p$. How can I connect the boundedness of $f$ to the boundedness of general solution?

How can I say $(*)$ can have at most one bounded solution?

Comment: You have a closed formula for the solution which would be a good place to start.

Comment: Alternatively, if you subtract any two particular solution, you get a solution to the homogeneous equation which as you say is unbounded. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: By the way, the general solutions will be $y = \lambda y_h + y_p$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, there is not just $y_h + y_p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded ($|f(t)| \le b$) then
$$
y(t)=e^{-t} \int_{-\infty}^t e^\tau f(\tau)d\tau
$$
is a bounded solution. Note that the integral is convergent since $f$ is bounded.

We have
$$
|y(t)| \le b e^{-t} \int_{-\infty}^t e^\tau d\tau = b \quad (t \in \mathbb{R}).
$$
The proper initial value is therefore $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^\tau f(\tau)d\tau$.

Answer (score 2):

You already figured out that the homogeneous equation is unbounded. Suppose that there are two bounded solutions $y_1, y_2$. Thus $\tilde y:=y_1 - y_2$ is bounded and satisfies the associated homogeneous equation. But if $\tilde y\not \equiv 0$, then it is unbounded by your remark (every solution of the homogeneous equation is $c e^{-t}$ for some $c$). Thus $\tilde y \equiv 0 \implies y_1 \equiv y_2$, proving uniqueness.

To show that there is a bounded solution, use the usual, explicit method to find a solution and try to choose an initial value good enough such that $|f(t)| \le M$ actually gives you boundness. You can multiply by an integrating factor $\mu = e^t$, so $e^t y' + e^t y = e^t f \iff (e^t y)' = e^t f \iff y(t) = (c + \int_{-\infty}^te^\tau f(\tau) d\tau)e^{-t}$. In particular, $|y(t)| \le ce^{-t} + e^{-t}\int_{-\infty}^t e^\tau |f(\tau)| d\tau \le ce^{-t} + Me^{-t}\int_{-\infty}^t e^\tau d\tau = ce^{-t} + M$. so $c = 0$ in fact gives boundness for both positive and negative $t$; i.e.,

$$y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t e^\tau f(\tau)d\tau$$ is our bounded solution.

Comment: I think you missed the factor $e^{-t}$ in the last bounded solution.